# Magento custom block breaks site. Why?

Tags: magento, block, magento-1.7

I am working on a custom block for magento 1.7. I have the block declared as such in my config xml. This module also has a controller defined in it which is working fine. I needed a new block with some logic behind it, so I figured I'd use a module I already created. I've included the block declaration below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Company_Catalog>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Company_Catalog>
</modules>
<global>
    <blocks>
        <catalog>
            <class>Company_Catalog_Block</class>
        </catalog>
    </blocks>
</global>
</config>
```

I've used the block in a local.xml in my theme using this syntax:

```
<block type="catalog/featured" name="featuredproducts" before="-" template="catalog/featured.phtml"/>
```

The block appears like I want it to, but the problem is that most of the rest of the site is broken and exception.log is full of magento looking for other blocks in my module. Examples:

```
2012-11-27T19:34:47+00:00 ERR (3):
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type:Company_Catalog_Block_Product_List' in /home/project/site_content/app/Mage.php:594
2012-11-27T19:34:47+00:00 ERR (3):
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: Company_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar' in /home/project/site_content/app/Mage.php:594
```

I don't want to rewrite any existing blocks, just add a new one in a module I already declared.

I've obviously told Magento to look in my module for more than what I want it to. This is my first attempt at working with custom blocks in Magento, so I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

I understand "Catalog" is used in the Mage namespace as well, but I am working in my own namespace. From what I understand, there should be no conflict.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You are overwriting the original catalog block class prefix in *Mage/Catalog/etc/config.xml*:

```
<global>
    <blocks>
        <catalog>
            <class>Mage_Catalog_Block
```

By doing this, every request for a catalog block type (`type="catalog/..."`) the prefix used will be `Company_Catalog_Block`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So I take it that for blocks am I better off using a module that does not appear in the core at all. Correct?

Comment: @ddhahn If you want to create custom blocks, then yes, use a "group name" (i.e. "catalog") that isn't used by the core. My standard practice has been to use the full package/module name( i.e. < company_catalog>...</company_catalog>.  It's a little verbose, but avoids any possible namespace collisions.